# Handling 2 click events on the same element one after the other

Tags: jquery

There are 2 click events written on the same element. How to handle it to execute the events in an order. In one of the click event, the API is called and in another click event, page is redirected to other page. so, before the api is exceuted, the page redirection is happening where API is failing

Comment: Do you control the binding of the events? If so, change your code so you only bind a single event handler which performs both actions, the latter of which being done in the  promise/callback of the AJAX request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait for the response before running the rest of the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594683/how-to-wait-for-the-response-before-running-the-rest-of-the-code)

Comment: Hi Rory - No, i am not binding. Can you give some example